# How can I mvn:install shaded maven artifact

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-install-plugin

This should have been easy but I'm experiencing strange behavior from maven-install plug-in.

I needed to repackage some common dependencies into my project to avoid dependency conflicts. for that purpose I used shade plugin with relocations configured:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>do_shade</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                              <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                              <shadedPattern>com.myproject.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.commons</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>com.myproject.commons</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The shade plugin did it's job correctly and produced shaded artifact *com.myproject-myproject-.jar* and dependecy-reduced pom file. **But then install plugin installed the original artifact (without dependencies) instead of the shaded one**.

Further more, before that install plugin problem my CI server (jenkins) built the project and **correctly published the shaded artifact and dependency reduced pom to nexus repository** (!!). So now it I download the artifact from nexus, i'll have correct jars in my local repository, but if I use install plugin, the jars won't be good.

Has anyone had similar issues? Does anyone know how to resolve them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was that I later marked the dependencies-to-be-shaded as provided so that they don't get transitively pulled into my other projects. That caused shade plugin to not include them in shaded jar.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, where `mvn install` would build a shaded jar in my target directory but install the non-shaded one to my local Maven repository.

What ultimately proved to be the cause was that I had `<finalName>` defined in my maven-shade-plugin configuration. That ended up saving the shaded jar under that specific name, while the non-shaded jar took the default jar name which `mvn install` must look for when it comes time to install. Without `<finalName>` present, it copied the shaded jar appropriately into the local Maven repository.